# MobX + React Native : way to inject stores

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobx, feathersjs, mobx-react

I'm trying to work with MobX for a new project.
I started it on May 2017, and everything was working well. I had to stop, and now I go on developing it. I had to make an `npm install` to manage making it working, but now, I have some problem with stores...
I rely on this **tutorial** for the structure : https://blog.callstack.io/write-react-native-apps-in-2017-style-with-mobx-e2dffc209fcb

This is my **structure** :

> Main index.js

```
import { Provider } from 'mobx-react';
import Stack from './router';
import stores from './stores';

export default class App extends Component {

      render() {
        return (
          <Provider {...stores}>
            <Stack />
          </Provider>
        );
      }
    }
```

> Index.js of my stores in ./stores/index.js

```
import ChatStore from './ChatStore';
import UserStore from './UserStore';

export default {
  UserStore: new UserStore(),
  ChatStore: new ChatStore(),
};
```

> ./stores/UserStore.js (important parts)

```
import { observer, inject } from 'mobx-react';
import {autobind} from 'core-decorators';
...
@inject(['ChatStore'])
@observer
@autobind
export default class UserStore {

  @observable isAuthenticated = false;
  @observable isConnecting = false;
  @observable user = null;
  @observable messages = [];
  @observable hasMoreMessages = false;
  @observable skip = 0;
...
login() {
    const payload = {
      strategy: 'local',
      material_id: DeviceInfo.getManufacturer(),
      password: DeviceInfo.getManufacturer()
    };
    return this.authenticate(payload);
  }
...
```

Now, for components part :

> Router.js

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import Home from './containers/Home';

const stackNavigatorConfig = {
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
};

export default StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
  },
}, stackNavigatorConfig);
```

> ./containers/Home.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { observable } from 'mobx';
import { observer, inject } from 'mobx-react';

@inject('UserStore')
@observer
export default class Home extends Component {
  props: Props;
...
render() {
    this.props.UserStore.login().catch(error => {
       console.log('LOGIN', 'ERROR', JSON.stringify(error), error.message);
    });

   return {
    ...
   }
}
```

And then, I get an error : 
[image: Error]

So, I sum up :

1. I use `<Provider>` from MobX, to **give all my stores** to my app
2. Then, I get the Store I want in my component with **@inject**
3. I use it as a **props**, using `this.props.UserStore`...
   But it does not work. I rely on this tutorial for the structure : https://blog.callstack.io/write-react-native-apps-in-2017-style-with-mobx-e2dffc209fcb

Maybe there was an update between May 2017 and today, that makes things different... It was working well on May 2017.
*I think this is a dummy error, but I can't find which one...*

Comment: Have you tried removing `@inject(['ChatStore']) @observer @autobind` from your `UserStore` class?

Comment: John - did you end up finding solution for your problem? I am having exactly the same issue, but I do not have autobind and observer in my store, so I am not sure what to do

Comment: Actually, in my case I forgot to instantiate my store before I passed it using Provider. In case anyone else will make the same silly mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything looks good except the decorators on your `UserStore` class: `@inject(['ChatStore']) @observer @autobind`. `@inject(['ChatStore']) @observer` is used on React components, `@autobind` might still work as intended.

It should work if you remove those.

Answer (score 0):

maybe worth using @action from mobx